# Canvas with IE not Working

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9

Is there any particular canvas available on internet which supports IE. I want to draw something on the canvas and save the foll as image. I have couple of canvas but then it fails when i try to work it on IE9. Help really appreciated! :)

Comment: Canvas should work on IE9. Something else may be going on. See http://caniuse.com/canvas

Comment: the code is too long. it wont accept here. i have html file. is there any other way i can show it to you?

Comment: Guys it Worked.. Thanks for ya help. actually it askd me to allow the blocked content. as soon as i did it.. It worked.. Thanks for ya help tho. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"canvas" is supported in IE9 but the implementation of some of the APIs may not be available.

- You can access samples from the following [link](http://risingtrends.com/blog/learning-html5-canvas-through-jsfiddle-examples/).
- Also, please note that some of the specifications for HTML5/canvas
  are still in draft.
- Refer [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element) to understand how various browsers support "canvas".
- "caniuse.com" is a good place to check for compatibility [caniuse

  canvas](http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas)